# Using Google.Apis.Analytics.v3

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to use Google.Apis.Analytics.v3 for the 1st time, programmatically. We are building dashboard pages to show statistics, within their organisation-until now I have been reporting on information from internal databases.

Now we want to retrieve data from our Google analytics account.

My main tool for development is visual studio and C#. Some of the webpages have been created just using text editors, by a colleague, but I'm happier doing it in visual studio. We are sharing this development with organisations who do not use visual studio. So when I finish work on my webpages, we make 2 small changes to my files and we can be used without needing visual studio.

I have experience also in JavaScript and some jscript. I did find the Google API nuget package for studio and have installed it (not had time to look at it yet).

Some options Google have on their help site involves languages such as Java that we don't have any experience of in the format they appeared to be using it.

Given the above, can someone advise or recommend the best approach I should take for retrieving Google analytics data into our webpages (I do not want users to have to login-it should just seamlessly retrieve the data and display it).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could make an MVC project, where you can take the data and display it in a `View`. Here you can see some example with [GoogleApi and MVC project in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731995/how-can-i-make-a-server-to-server-authentication-to-google-drive-api/50732047#50732047).